# What's a prefix regular expression?

Tags: regex

I'm reading something that mentions prefix regular expressions, and sites as an example /^joey/

What's a prefix regular expression? Does that mean it starts with a caret?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a standard term.  Whoever wrote that obviously means a regex that matches only at the beginning of the target text, as the other responders have said.  The caret is usually used for that purpose, but it can also mean the beginning of a logical line, if the match is being performed in multiline mode.  Many regex flavors support an additional construct that matches the very beginning of the text regardless of the matching mode, `\A` being its usual form.

For more details, [read this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

Answer (score 10):

in REGEX `^` at the start of a regex means, "Starts with"

```
/^joey/
```

Would therefore match any string that starts with `"joey"` such as `"joeyjoey"` or `"joey and jane"`

Comment: The op is not asking the meaning of ^ . The question is "what is a prefix regular expression"

Answer (score 6):

A prefixed regular expression (PRE) is defined recursively

- Empty set ø end empty string ""- are PREs
- For each symbol a in alphabet, "a" is a PRE
- If p and q are PREs denoting the regular sets P and Q, respectively, r is a regular expression denoting the regular set R such that e belongs to R, and x belongs to S, then the following expressions are also PREs:

  - p + q (union )
  - xp (concatenation with symbol x on the left) .
  - pr (concatenation with an e-regular on the right)
  - p* (star) .

This definition was taken from "Fast Text Searching for Regular Expressions or
Automaton Searching on Tries" work by RICARDO A. BAEZA-YATES and GASTON H. GONNET

In other words PRE means Regular Expression that language L has only strings with some fixed prefix. 
abc.* - is PRE
(A|B)cd - is not PRE

Answer (score 1):

The caret means that you match the start of a string for example /^joey/ will match "joey is there" since the string starts with "joey" but not "Is joey around?" since joey is in the middle of the sentence.

Comment: You could have copied the below answer and posted it :P

Comment: Well, I was writing the answer when the other came :) And mine contains a counter-example by the way :P