Failed to search a substring in mongodb text search
I have implemented search functionality in my application where the user able to search across the database. So for that I have applied text index on one of the field named title. I am using the below query for searching:
let data = await reports.find({ active: true, $text: { $search: title } });

Let's say I have one report having title is "Random market" when user is entering full word "random", it's only fetching the data and if user is entering "ran" then its returning an empty array. How can I modify it to achieve desired functionality?

@regex may be the way forward. Downcasing is a small technique used in addition to give users the freedom for case-insensitive search. With downcasing, the query would remain efficient via indexing though there is a data duplication. However if the expression is not a "prefix expression", then indexing still be helpless.   Q&A referenced: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63444369/mongodb-query-combining-text-search-with-regex     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878982/whats-a-prefix-regular-expression

let regex = new RegExp(title, 'i'); // 'i' flag for case-insensitive matching
let data = await reports.find({ active: true, title: { $regex: regex } });

